# SQL Conditional Filtering On Int Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which is collecting responses from students. I am going to run a stored procedure to get all of the student's responses and handle all of the pagination, sorting, and filtering. The problem I am encountering is with an int column that is going to store a count of how many profanities were found in their response. I will have a filter that will have the options of Yes/No/All that will determine if you want to see responses with profanity, without, or both. I'm not sure how to possibly get a case statement in my where clause that can handle all 3 cases.

Essentially I need something like similar to this in my where. The @profanity is going to be a variable sent into the stored procedure that is going to be either true, false, or null.

```
WHERE 
(
  --OTHER FILTERS HERE
)
AND
(
    CASE
        -- if @profanity filter is true then we want all with counter greater than 0
        WHEN @Profanity = '1' THEN R.ProfanitiesFound > '0'
        -- else if @profanty filter is false then we want all with counter equal to 0
        WHEN @Profanity = '0' THEN R.ProfanitiesFound = '0'
        -- if nothing was sent in then just show all
        WHEN (@Profanity IS NULL OR @Profanity = '') THEN R.ProfanitiesFound = R.Profanities
    END
)
```

Not that the rest of the query is needed, but here it is:

```
;WITH CTE_Results
AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN @Column = 'Student' AND @Direction = 'asc' THEN u.LastName END asc,
        CASE WHEN @Column = 'Student' AND @Direction = 'desc' THEN u.LastName END desc,
        CASE WHEN @Column = 'Student' THEN u.FirstName END asc,
        CASE WHEN @Column = 'Classroom' AND @Direction = 'asc' THEN c.Name END asc,
        CASE WHEN @Column = 'Classroom' AND @Direction = 'desc' THEN c.Name END desc,
        CASE WHEN @Column = 'Classroom' THEN u.LastName END asc,
        CASE WHEN @Column = 'Lesson' AND @Direction = 'asc' THEN L.Name END asc,
        CASE WHEN @Column = 'Lesson' AND @Direction = 'desc' THEN L.Name END desc,
        CASE WHEN @Column = 'Lesson' THEN u.LastName END asc,
        CASE WHEN @Column = 'Page' AND @Direction = 'asc' THEN P.PageNumber END asc,
        CASE WHEN @Column = 'Page' AND @Direction = 'desc' THEN P.PageNumber END desc,
        CASE WHEN @Column = 'Page' THEN L.Name END asc,
        CASE WHEN @Column = 'QuestionType' AND @Direction = 'asc' THEN QT.Name END asc,
        CASE WHEN @Column = 'QuestionType' AND @Direction = 'desc' THEN QT.Name END desc,
        CASE WHEN @Column = 'QuestionType' THEN u.LastName END asc,
        CASE WHEN @Column = 'Attempt' AND @Direction = 'asc' THEN R.Attempt END asc,
        CASE WHEN @Column = 'Attempt' AND @Direction = 'desc' THEN R.Attempt END desc,
        CASE WHEN @Column = 'Attempt' THEN u.LastName END asc,
        CASE WHEN @Column = 'TotalScore' AND @Direction = 'asc' THEN R.TotalScore END asc,
        CASE WHEN @Column = 'TotalScore' AND @Direction = 'desc' THEN R.TotalScore END desc,
        CASE WHEN @Column = 'TotalScore' THEN u.LastName END asc,
        CASE WHEN @Column = 'Created' AND @Direction = 'asc' THEN L.Name END asc,
        CASE WHEN @Column = 'Created' AND @Direction = 'desc' THEN L.Name END desc,
        CASE WHEN @Column = 'Created' THEN u.LastName END asc
    ) AS ROWNUM,
    COUNT(*) OVER () AS TotalCount, C.Id AS 'ClassroomId', C.Name AS 'ClassroomName', U.Id AS 'UserId', U.LastName, U.FirstName, QT.Name AS 'QuestionType',
    R.TotalScore, R.ProfanitiesFound, R.HasGaming, R.Created, R.Response, R.Attempt, R.IsPassingScore,
    L.Name AS 'LessonName', P.PageNumber
    FROM Responses R
    INNER JOIN AspNetUsers U ON U.Id = R.UserId
    INNER JOIN ClassroomUsers CU ON CU.UserId = U.Id
    INNER JOIN Classrooms C ON C.Id = CU.ClassroomId
    INNER JOIN Schools S ON S.Id = C.SchoolId
    INNER JOIN Districts D ON D.Id = S.DistrictId
    INNER JOIN Questions Q ON Q.Id = R.QuestionId
    INNER JOIN QuestionTypes QT ON QT.Id = Q.QuestionTypeId
    INNER JOIN Pages P ON P.Id = Q.PageId
    INNER JOIN Lessons L ON L.Id = P.LessonId
    WHERE
    ( 
        (@Filter IS NULL OR U.LastName LIKE LOWER('%'+@Filter+'%'))
        OR (@Filter IS NULL OR U.FirstName LIKE LOWER('%'+@Filter+'%'))
        OR (@Filter IS NULL OR L.Name LIKE LOWER('%'+@Filter+'%'))
        OR (@Filter IS NULL OR QT.Name LIKE LOWER('%'+@Filter+'%'))
    )
    AND
    (
        U.Id  = CASE WHEN (@Student <> '' AND @Student IS NOT NULL) THEN @Student ELSE U.Id END AND
        D.Id  = CASE WHEN (@District <> '' AND @District IS NOT NULL) THEN @District ELSE D.Id END AND
        S.Id  = CASE WHEN (@School <> '' AND @School IS NOT NULL) THEN @School ELSE S.Id END AND
        C.Id  = CASE WHEN (@Classroom <> '' AND @Classroom IS NOT NULL) THEN @Classroom ELSE C.Id END AND
        QT.Id = CASE WHEN (@QuestionType <> '' AND @QuestionType IS NOT NULL) THEN @QuestionType ELSE QT.Id END AND
        Q.Id  = CASE WHEN (@Question <> '' AND @Question IS NOT NULL) THEN @Question ELSE Q.Id END AND
        L.Id  = CASE WHEN (@Lesson <> '' AND @Lesson IS NOT NULL) THEN @Lesson ELSE L.Id END AND
        R.HasGaming = CASE WHEN (@Gaming <> '' AND @Gaming IS NOT NULL) THEN @Gaming ELSE R.HasGaming END   
    )
    AND
    (
        --TODO: WOULD EVENTUALLY LIKE TO MAKE THESE FILTERS NOT REQUIRED
        R.TotalScore >= @FirstScore AND R.TotalScore <= @SecondScore
    )
    AND
    (
        CASE
            -- if @profanity filter is true then we want all with counter greater than 0
            WHEN @Profanity = '1' THEN R.ProfanitiesFound > '0'
            -- else if @profanty filter is false then we want all with counter equal to 0
            WHEN @Profanity = '0' THEN R.ProfanitiesFound = '0'
            -- if nothing was sent in then just show all
            WHEN (@Profanity IS NULL OR @Profanity = '') THEN R.ProfanitiesFound = R.Profanities
        END
    )

)

SELECT TotalCount, ClassroomId, ClassroomName, UserId, LastName, FirstName, QuestionType, TotalScore, ProfanitiesFound, HasGaming, Created, Response, Attempt, IsPassingScore, LessonName, PageNumber
FROM CTE_Results
WHERE ROWNUM > @FirstRec AND ROWNUM < @LastRec
```

Comment: CASE is an expression. It is used to return a scalar value. It is NOT used to control flow or logic. Also is ProfanitiesFound a string datatype?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a `CASE` statement to do this, you can do it directly in the `WHERE` clause, like so:

```
WHERE 
(
  --OTHER FILTERS HERE
)
AND
(
    -- if @profanity filter is true then we want all with counter greater than 0
    (@Profanity = '1' AND R.ProfanitiesFound > '0')
    OR
    -- else if @profanty filter is false then we want all with counter equal to 0
    (@Profanity = '0' AND R.ProfanitiesFound = '0')
    OR
    -- if nothing was sent in then just show all
    ((@Profanity IS NULL OR @Profanity = '') AND R.ProfanitiesFound = R.Profanities)
)
```

Comment: I tried this and for some reason when I set Profanity to '0' it returns all of the values. Not exactly sure what is going on yet. Same results when I actually add this stored procedure and send in true/false through c# .net

Comment: `SET @Profanity = '0'
...  
AND
  (
   -- if @profanity filter is true then we want all with counter greater than 0
   (@Profanity = '1' AND R.ProfanitiesFound >= '1')
   OR
   -- else if @profanty filter is false then we want all with counter equal to 0
   (@Profanity = '0' AND R.ProfanitiesFound = '0')
   OR
   -- if nothing was sent in then just show all
   ((@Profanity IS NULL OR @Profanity = '') AND R.ProfanitiesFound = R.ProfanitiesFound)
  )`

Comment: If you ignore the `@Profanity` variable and use a simple where clause of `WHERE R.ProfanitiesFound = '0'` does it also bring back all records?

Comment: Yes that works. Also I noticed that if I take out the 3rd case of checking if it is null or blank it also works if I have 0 or 1 set for profanity, however when I set the var to null it then returns nothing. So it would seem to be that it is something related to the 3rd case that is causing this to misfire.

Comment: Actually I think it is because I have Profanity as a bit and the Profanity = '' was doing it. When I remove that part and just check for null it works I think.

Comment: I was just about to ask what data type Profanity was. Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1):

You Can use AND OR logic insted of case when as follows

```
OR( @Profanity = '1' AND R.ProfanitiesFound > '0')

OR( @Profanity = '0' AND R.ProfanitiesFound = '0')

OR((@Profanity IS NULL AND @Profanity = '') or R.ProfanitiesFound = R.Profanities)
```